# PHP Array variable Declare as alias

Tags: php, codeigniter

I will declare an array just once. Value would like to call again and again as the key alias. please any one can help me?
example:

I have :

```
<?php
$id =  $profile[0]->id;
$roll = $profile[0]->roll;
$photo = $profile[0]->photo;
$active = $profile[0]->active;
?>
```

I neeed :

```
<?php
$var as $profile[0];
$id =  $var->id;
$roll = $var->roll;
$photo = $var->photo;
$active = $var->active;
?>
```

It can be done with foreach () . However, I would like to work on Alias.
i need any good idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this

```
    <?php
    // this line you can try
    $var = array();

    // your code
    $var = $profile[0];
    $id =  $var->id;
    $roll = $var->roll;
    $photo = $var->photo;
    $active = $var->active;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($profile[0] as $key => $val) {
    $$key = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `list()` construct for this purpose.

```
list($profile) = $profiles;
$id = $profile->id;
$roll = $profile->roll;
$photo = $profile->photo;
$active = $profile->active;
```

The variable `$profile` is equivalent to `$profiles[0]`. So, you could stick with this way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of what you're looking for but I feel you're after [references](http://php.net/references), more specifically to [assign by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.assign):

```
$profile = array(
    0 => (object)array(
        'id' => '314',
        'roll' => 'XYZ',
        'photo' => 'foo.jpg',
        'active' => true,
    ),
);

$var = &$profile[0];

$id =  $var->id;
$roll = $var->roll;
$photo = $var->photo;
$active = $var->active;

var_dump($id, $roll, $photo, $active);
```

```
string(3) "314"
string(3) "XYZ"
string(7) "foo.jpg"
bool(true)
```

Now `$var` is a variable name that points to the same object that `$profile[0]` that you can modify it through either variables:

```
$var->photo = 'flowers.gif';
var_dump($profile);
```

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  &object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "314"
    ["roll"]=>
    string(3) "XYZ"
    ["photo"]=>
    string(11) "flowers.gif"
    ["active"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
}
```

Of course, all this is kind of overkill if you don't actually need to alter the original array and this would suffice:

```
$var = $profile[0];
```